# QGIS - Vector Menu no longer working

Tags: qgis

The Vector menu no longer works.  All the other menus drop down and show the different options available. Here is the error message shown upon startup. I do not know if this is linked to the Vector menu or if two different problems.

```
2019-03-24T14:06:40     WARNING    Python error : Couldn't load plugin 'NITK_RS-GIS_17' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method See message log (Python Error) for more details.
2019-03-24T14:06:42     WARNING    Plugin processing : The plugin will be disabled because it crashed QGIS during last startup. Please report an issue and re-enable the plugin when the problem has been solved.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reinstalling plugins the vector Menu worked again.

Comment: If this your answer that solved your problem you can now accept it, this takes it out of the unanswered category